# SetLength and multidimensional dynamic array

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I have to work with arrays of arrays of Tpoint. I don't know any initial dimension because the user will be able to create n groups of Point each of which with variable dimension.

It involves working with figures, each initial figure has four vertices and it is possible to model it, add and remove vertices.

I define the type

```
type
Tnode = array of array of TPoint;
...
Fnode: Tnode;
```

When I create a new figure I initialize the array

```
SetLength(Fnode, index, 5);
```

Then I modify the figure by adding and removing vertices, setting the new dimension each time

```
SetLength(fnode[index-1], nVertices);
```

Everything works best but when I create a new starting figure with `SetLength (Fnode, newIndex, 5)` the previous array is also initialized to 5 again and any vertices added are obviously deleted.

At the moment I solved by copying the arrays before creating a new figure and restoring them after calling SetLength but it seems like bad practice.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `SetLength(Fnode, newIndex); SetLength(Fnode[newIndex-1], 5);`

Comment: BTW that thing you call index should be named count

Comment: Just a comment: With this structure (dynamic array of dynamic array), you'll have poor performances if the size of the arrays change frequently and you'll have memory fragmentation easily. The advantage it simplicity. A more efficient - seen from memory allocation performance - would be to use dynamically linked lists: one for figures and one per figure for vertices.